# Connect dynamic data with google marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to connect my dynamic data with google map marker here is my code

this is my `mapdata` and `listdata` both having same value which coming from the php

```
latitude: "19.1904917"
logitude: "72.8639419"
name: "Monkey d luffy"
```

using this `latitude` and `logitude` i m showing google marker on map for show marker data i used this code

```
    var defaultLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0822508,72.8812041); 
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            panControl:false,
            streetViewControl:false,
            center: defaultLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControl:true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
              style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
        };
loadMap();
function loadMap(){

   console.log('loadMap');

   // create new map make sure a DIV with id myMap exist on page
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), myOptions);
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   //oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,{markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true});
   // create new info window for marker detail pop-up

        $.each(mapdata.locations,function(key,val){           
                loadMarker(val);
         }); 
        $.each(listdata.locations,function(key,val){    
                loaddata(val);
         });  
}
```

this is my `loadmarker` function which showing marker on google maps

```
function loadMarker(markerData)
{   

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData['latitude'],markerData['logitude']);
   console.log(myLatlng);
  // create new marker                
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        title: markerData['address'],
        position: myLatlng
        //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });   
     marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'); 

    gmarkers.push(marker);
    var marker_num = gmarkers.length-1;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        showMarker(markerData,marker);
    });

}
```

this is my `loaddata` function which is `showing my data on UI`

```
function loaddata(markerData)
{     
    listitem += "<div class='expert_name'>"
                   +markerData['name']+
                 +"</div>"                            
    $('#_mymaplist').html(listitem);
}
```

this is my html where i add all this thing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Multiple Markers Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="mymap" style="width: 800px; height:500px;"></div>
        <div id="_mymaplist" style="width: 800px; height:500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want when i hover name from `_mymaplist` div then google marker color has to change for the example here i only give one data but there will be more than one

i checked many example like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_mw_example_hoverchange.html)  but i won't  work for me
because this example having same function for loading the data..but in my case i have 2 function to load data. i also can use 1 function but problem is that map marker loading all data at one time and the list data is using pagination form loading data....so that y i can't use same function for loading data Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Because of the issue of pagination if you have to use 2 functions, you can use the [Styled Marker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r161/trunk/styledmarker/docs/examples.html) in the loaddata() function itself where you are defining your individual markers. For that you will need to use set(property, value) methods.

```
this.styleIcon.set('color', '00fff0');
```

This has to be defined inside your loaddata() function where your listitems are initialized.

```
function createStyle() { return new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE,{color:"#95AA7B",text:"click me!",fore:"#ffffff"}); }

listitem += "<div class='expert_name'>"
               +markerData['name']+
             +"</div>"                            
$('#_mymaplist').html(listitem);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker4,"click", function(o){
    this.styleIcon.set("fore","#ffffff");//test color
    this.styleIcon.set("color","#C2554D");// background color
    this.styleIcon.set("text","color changed");
});
```

Hope this would Help!!